# AppCenter app page to show "Play Game" button

Tags: facebook, center

We have launched an Android app (http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/christmasslotmachine) first, and the "Send to Mobile" button on the appcenter page works great, but we have also now introduced a Facebook version of the game, and this too is now working correctly at http://apps.facebook.com/christmasslotmachine/.

At present, the appcenter page is only giving the option to "Send to Mobile" and not "Play Game". It also is only reporting the game as being available on: Android instead of Android & Facebook.

An important note, is that the "Play Game" link on the community page - http://www.facebook.com/ChristmasSlotMachines - is working fine also.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you resubmit the app center submission for approval and select that you also wanted to highlight your app on facebook?

Comment: Thank you Igy. This simple step (which had been missed) has now solved it!